# Get the_content surrounded by <h1> instead of <p>

Tags: php, filters, the-content

I'm looking to use the_content() on a particular page, but I want it to be surrounded with an `<h1>` instead of a `<p>`.

I've tried doing this:

```
$thisPagesContent = the_content();
echo '<h1' . $thisPagesContent . '</h1>';
```

This works, but it strips the `<br>` tag that I have in the content.

Any way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic, but why would you want to wrap the content of a page in an H1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the HTML Of the content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303952/changing-the-html-of-the-content)

Answer (score 1):

First you should use [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) to assign the content to a variable (instead of [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) which is meant to display it instead of returning it).

Then you will want to apply filters hooked to `'the_content'` just like `the_content()` does (see the [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/#source)).

Here is a revised version of your original code:

```
$thisPagesContent = get_the_content();
$thisPagesContent = apply_filters( 'the_content', $thisPagesContent );
$thisPagesContent = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $thisPagesContent );
echo '<h1>' . $thisPagesContent . '</h1>';
```

An alternative way to approach it would be to create a filter in the `functions.php` file of your theme or child theme or in a plugin and hook it to `'the_content'`, with a conditional so that it only applies to the target page.
On said page, you would then just call `the_content()` as normal and the filter would apply. This approach would more neatly separate content manipulation and presentation.

Example:

```
function wpst_304021_wrap_content_in_h1( $content ) {

    if ( is_page( '123' ) ) { // Assuming your "target" page's ID is '123', you can also use the page's title or slug or another conditional altogether.
        return '<h1>' . $content . '</h1>';
    }

   return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wpst_304021_wrap_content_in_h1');
```

As an aside, I do hope you have a specific use case with a good reason do to this, as wrapping the whole content of a post in a heading tag would be a terrible idea in most cases.

Comment: I tried these, the first wrapped the content in an <h1>, but the p was still inside of it.

Comment: If you additionally don't want any `p` tags to be included automatically, you'll need to disable wpautop, which one of the filters hooked to `the_content`. Adding `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` just before calling apply_filters (second line), should do the trick.